# Issues with simple client server program

Tags: java, client-server

I have written two-way client-server communication in which client first sends the message and then server sends the reply. However, client is blocked while reading the reply sent by server( i.e Nothing is printed at client side however, server has sent the reply correctly). Below is the code :-

Server code:-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server
{
    // Socket for accepting connections.
    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try
        {
            int port = 2550;
            // Creating server socket on specified port.
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server started listening on port "+port);

            while(true)
            {
                // Accept the connection and read the message.
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream()));
                String message = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Message recieved from client is :- " + message);

                // Prepare and send the response back to client.
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( socket.getOutputStream()));
                String reply = "Thanks.Your reply has been recieved";
                bw.write(reply);
                bw.flush();
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch( Exception e )
            {
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Client code :-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client
{
    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try
        {
            String host = "localhost";
            int port = 2550;

            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            socket = new Socket(address, port);

            // Send the message to the server.
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( socket.getOutputStream()));
            String message = "This is the message from Client.\n";
            bw.write(message);
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to the server :- " + message);

            // Get the reply from the server.
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream()));
            String reply = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message recieved from the server :- " + reply);
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Closing the socket.
            try
            {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch( Exception e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

D:\Java_P>java Server
Server started listening on port 2550
Message recieved from client is :- This is the message from Client.

D:\Java_P>java Client
Message sent to the server :- This is the message from Client.
```

I

Comment: Is it possible that the internal socket connection to the server is fast enough that the server sends a reply before the client creates a reader to capture it?  Also, did you launch two separate terminals, or just one to run both programs?

Comment: In the client code, try creating the `BufferedReader` before sending the message. Since client and server run at the same time, the server * might * send the reply before the client is able to receive it.

Comment: @Gliderman I also doubt it. Yes I launched separate terminals.@Uber Tried that also with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your server sends "Thanks. Your reply has been recieved" which does not contain any newline character. Reason is because in the client, buffered reader readline method blocks till it finds a newline character.

Make following changes:

```
String reply = "Thanks.Your reply has been recieved\nDummy line 1";
```

Now you can see the lines in your client logs.

Comment: :) . I faced the same issue recently. I was trying to implement my own simple web server.